# extconf.rb: How do I generate makefile targets dependent upon header file changes?

Tags: c++, c, ruby, extconf.rb, mkmf

In my `extconf.rb`, I have

```
$srcs = %w{foo.cpp bar.cpp}
$objs = %w{foo bar}
```

Each of these is dependent upon multiple header files. If I `touch foo.cpp` or `touch bar.cpp`, and then do `rake compile`, it recompiles the appropriate object file.

But touching a `.h` file doesn't have the same effect, obviously. I can't remember if this is a symptom of my use of `extconf.rb` or just a fact of coding in C/C++.

Is there some way I can direct `extconf.rb` to write a makefile that is aware of these header files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do it directly within the `extconf.rb`; for whatever reason, `mkmf` uses a separate file, named `depend`, to specify these sorts of things.  You put all of your dependencies in the same form you would if you were writing a makefile by hand; so, for a file `foo.cpp` that used `client.h` and `wombat.h`, you would add the following line to `depend`:

```
foo.o: client.h wombat.h`
```

In the process of building your `Makefile`, `mkmf` will copy the contents of that file into your `Makefile`, causing those rules to be honoured as part of the build process.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. I had no idea that's what the `depend` file did, but now that you say it, I remember seeing that in lots of projects. Good to know.